# Combine 2 dataframes when the dataframes have different size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 df one is

```
df1 = {'col_1': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
df2 = {'col_1': [3, 2, 1, 3]}
```

I want the result as follows

```
df3 = {'col_1': [3, 2, 1, 3], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']}
```

The column 2 of the new df is the same as the column 2 of the df1 depending on the value of the df1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the new column by mapping the values from df1 after setting its first column as index:

```
df3 = df2.copy()
df3['col_2'] = df2['col_1'].map(df1.set_index('col_1')['col_2'])
```

output:

```
   col_1 col_2
0      3     a
1      2     b
2      1     c
3      3     a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `merge` after converting the dicts to df with `pd.DataFrame()`:

```
output = pd.DataFrame(df2)
output = output.merge(pd.DataFrame(df1),on='col_1',how='left')
```

Or in a one-liner:

```
output = pd.DataFrame(df2).merge(pd.DataFrame(df1),on='col_1',how='left')
```

Outputs:

```
   col_1 col_2
0      3     a
1      2     b
2      1     c
3      3     a
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a simple way of doing it.

```
# use df1 to create a lookup dictionary
lookup = df1.set_index("col_1").to_dict()["col_2"]

# look up each value from df2's "col_1" in the lookup dict
df2["col_2"] = df2["col_1"].apply(lambda d: lookup[d])
```